# How do I reset my passcode on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, security

I can't remember my passcode for my iPhone 5s—can I reset the passcode?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

Recovery mode is the only solution.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1808

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup on an Apple computer, there is a program which can scan the backup (if you have the password for the backup, or it's not password-protected) and dig out the passcode.

I have installed https://pinfinder.net and found it useful on more than one occasion (kids ...) though the web site says it does not support IOS 13.

Here's another which I have not tried: https://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/guides/recover-screen-time-parental-restrictions-passcode/